# How to access local xml file from resource in Android?

Tags: android, xml, resources

I am new to Android application, create one xml file `data.xml` inside the Resource folder, then i tried to access that local xml file, but i can't get it.

But android resource folder and open rawresource to the raw folder under res inside xml file
`data.xml` using this way, i access that xml file like:

```
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
```

but using local xml file cannot access, please help me.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Add your local file in assets buddy, and open file using file protocol

Comment: How to insert xml file inside the assets buddy?

Comment: ok, i insert the xml file inside assets, then how to access this xml file like InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

raw xmls should be in Assets folder, and to access files from assets folder use:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream in= assetManager.open("data.xml");
```

Comment: How to insert xml file inside the assets folder?

Comment: Ok i insert the xml file inside tha assets, then hoe to access

Comment: add by simply copying and pasting into assets folder.and then delete original one in eclipse.

Comment: how to access this xml file? like InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);

Comment: see, my edited answer. by that method you would get an input stream. and then parse the xml using some xml parser.

Comment: but local xml file access inside the res, possible or not.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14385/discussion-between-minu-and-jeet)

Answer (score 0):

Add your `data.xml` file under `raw folder`.After inserting into it you will not get this sort of error.